# How to fix Each then() should return a value or throw

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to build my server for firebase notifications, and I've watched a youtube video that showed how to write that javascript code, and I copied and pasted the code, while adjusting some paths to match my firebase database, but I have no idea what went wrong and I kind of don't know how to write in javascript.
So this is the code:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((data, context) => {
    const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    console.log('We have a notification to send to :' , receiver_user_id);

    if (!data.after.val()) {
        console.log('A notification has been deleted :' , notification_id);
    }

    const sender_user_id=admin.database().ref('/Notifications/${receiver_user_id}/${notification_id}').once('value');
    return sender_user_id.then(fromUserResult => {
        const from_sender_user_id=fromUserResult.val().from;
        console.log('you have a notification from :',sender_user_id);
        const userQuery=admin.database.ref('/Users/${receiver_user_id}/messaging_token`').once('value');
        return userQuery.then(userResult => {
            const senderUserName=userResult.val();
            return null;
        });

        const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiver_user_id}/messaging_token`).once('value');

        return DeviceToken.then(result => {
            const token_id = result.val();

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    from_sender_user_id:from_sender_user_id,
                    title: "New Chat Request",
                    body: `${senderUserName} offered you a lesson, Please Check.`,
                    icon: "default"
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
            .then(response => {
                    console.log('This was a notification feature.');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And these are the errors and warnings I'm getting:

```
26:44  warning  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string  
31:38  warning  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string  
32:10  warning  Avoid nesting promises                 promise/no-nesting 
38:3   error    Unreachable code                       no-unreachable 
40:10  warning  Avoid nesting promises                 promise/no-nesting
```

Any help would be really appriciated :)

Comment: The linting errors are all pretty self-explanatory... have you tried changing your code to fix them?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would if I knew how, I don't really get the reasons for the failures, I have tried some stuff but the errors keep on coming in different forms... I mean, I literaly copied what the tutorial said, but the unreachable statement shouldn't appear, since it worked in the video

Comment: You have `return`s followed by further statements in the same block - clearly, those further statements will never be reached, because the function will have necessarily returned before then. If a video had this code, the video would be wrong, following your linting rules

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah I understood why it wouldn't work, but for some weird reason every one in the comment section were quite thankful for the code writer, meaning they compiled it w/out errors... So I'm wondering if you have any suggestion as to how would it work and reach the following statements

Answer (score 0):

The first two warnings are caused by this line:

```
const sender_user_id=admin.database().ref('/Notifications/${receiver_user_id}/${notification_id}').once('value');
```

And this line:

```
const userQuery=admin.database.ref('/Users/${receiver_user_id}/messaging_token`').once('value');
```

In both cases you're using `${...}` in the string to use a value from your code while building the path. This is known as [expansion of a template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). But your strings are enclosed in single quotes `'`, which means that it's not interpreted as a template string.

The solution is to use backticks in the code. So:

```
const sender_user_id=admin.database().ref(`/Notifications/${receiver_user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
```

And:

```
const userQuery=admin.database.ref(`/Users/${receiver_user_id}/messaging_token`').once('value`);
```

Note that you shouldn't use backticks in the line that declares the Cloud Function (`exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_id}')`), as that string is what literally should be passed to the firebase-functions module.

For more on this error, see the [ESLint documentation for the error message](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string). I recommend that you find the explanation for each warning/error you get and try to fix it yourself first, as it will prevent getting downvoted.